# Python; Dictionary iteration

Tags: python, list, for-loop, dictionary, iteration

```
z = []
for k, v in b.iteritems():
    if v == "Supplementary Assignment, Smith, Bowen":
        z.append(not k)
```

Hello, I am trying to iterate over values in a dict. The goal here is to `z.append()` all keys in '`b`' that do not contain the multiple values defined for `v` in the `if` statement. So, if dict '`b`' contains a key/value pair whose value was 'Smith' then that key would be excluded from the `z.append()` call while all other keys would be appended. Thanks for any help coming my way!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to test against a sequence or set using a membership test (`not in`):

```
z = []
for k, v in b.iteritems():
    if v not in {"Supplementary", "Assignment", "Smith", "Bowen"}:
        z.append(k)
```

or, more compact in a list comprehension:

```
z = [key for key, value in b.iteritems() if value not in {"Supplementary", "Assignment", "Smith", "Bowen"}]
```

This lists all keys in `b` whose value is not listed in the set.

If loop efficiency is of the utmost importance and you are using a Python version *before* 3.3, then store the set in a local variable first and use that in the loops:

```
z = []
excluded = {"Supplementary", "Assignment", "Smith", "Bowen"}
for k, v in b.iteritems():
    if v not in excluded:
        z.append(k)
```

or the list comp version:

```
excluded = {"Supplementary", "Assignment", "Smith", "Bowen"}
z = [key for key, value in b.iteritems() if value not in excluded]
```

Python 3.3 recognizes `in {...}` or `not in {...}` syntax (with a set) and optimizes the code to use a local `frozenset()` constant for the set literal.

Comment: OK great, thanks Martijn. I knew I was close, but wasn't aware of the `not in` keywords. Great, thanks again!

Comment: May be wrong...but wouldn't it be better to put this `{"Supplementary", "Assignment", "Smith", "Bowen"}` in a variable so that you aren't recreating it multiple times in the list comp?

Comment: @iCodez: It is a constant; loading it is rather fast. In Python 3.3 and up, it'll make the *set* a constant, in versions before that it'll load the strings as constants and execute `BUILD_SET` each loop iteration. Loading a constant is just as fast as loading a local.

Comment: @iCodez: I am starting to default to Python 3.3 in answers now unless I see proof of an earlier version of Python.

Comment: I was surprised by the `{'Supplementary', ...}` syntax initially. Shouldn't that be a list or tuple? Isn't it a syntax error this way? Only after trying it out did I notice that this is in fact valid python for writing a set. I didn't know they added it. (In python 2.7, now that I've googled it). You learn something every day :-)

Comment: Ok, sorry for the lack of clarity. My code is intended for python 2.7, so that set syntax should be alright?

Comment: Not a problem! Added a 'before 3.3' section too.

Comment: Martijn, I know comments shouldn't be used for lionizing a fellow member, but has anyone ever told you that you are a coding wizard? Thanks, again!